# Listening for Preference change

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am implementing Preferences according to [Google tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html). But I do not receive changes in my event listener. I realized that it is because I unregister the listener in `onResume`, like Google recommended. Did I miss something or is google advice wrong?

> For proper lifecycle management in the activity, we recommend that you
>   register and unregister your
>   SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener during the
>   onResume() and onPause() callbacks, respectively:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        case R.id.action_level: {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(this, GamePreferenceActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
 ...

protected void onPause() {
    Log.d(logTag, "onPause()");
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    sharedPref.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    super.onPause();
}

protected void onResume() {
    Log.d(logTag, "onResume()");
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    sharedPref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if (key.equals(MyPreferenceActivity.KEY_COMPLEXITY)) {
        String value = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "EASY");
        logic.setLevel(Level.valueOf(value));
        restartGame(null);
    }
}
```

My activity starts an intent with preferences activity.

```
public class GamePreferenceActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String KEY_COMPLEXITY = "prefGameComplexity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new GamePreferenceFragment())
                .commit();

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.game_prefs, false);
    }
}

public class GamePreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.game_prefs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `onResume()` implementation? Documentation seems to be right. You register within `onResume()` and unregister within `onPause()`.

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: Looks good. What about your listener implementation?

Comment: When you are making changes to your Shared Preferences, are you calling commit() at the end?

Comment: No, I do not. There was no such code in google example. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @MateuszHerych implementation of onSharedPreferenceChanged is never called.

Comment: I still wonder, if the commit is relevant - because when Preferences activity is started, the onResume will unregister the listener.

Comment: Due to the fact that you want to listen to changes in the PreferenceFragment you can use onPreferenceChange() to get informed when a pref (GUI) changes. Keep in mind OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener != OnPreferenceChangeListener. 
You may have missed to link something. It would be great to see more code, to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call [`commit()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()) or [`apply()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) to save changes in preferences.

**Example:**

```
// Access the default SharedPreferences
    SharedPreferences preferences = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    // The SharedPreferences editor - must use commit() to submit changes
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    // Edit the saved preferences
    editor.putString("UserName", "JaneDoe");
    editor.putInt("UserAge", 22);
    editor.commit(); //or editor.apply() -- Read below for difference between these two
```

**Difference between [`commit()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()) and [`apply()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()):**

[`apply()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) was added in 2.3, it commits without returning a boolean indicating success or failure.

[`commit()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()) returns true if the save works, false otherwise.

[`apply()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) was added as the Android dev team noticed that almost no one took notice of the return value, so apply is faster as it is asynchronous.

Comment: Can you provide complete source sample? I just found commit in some SharedPreferences.Editor class.

Comment: Nice explanation, I upvoted your work. But I still did not get how it relates to my use case. I do not have a problems with serializing changed data - implementation of PreferenceFragment is doing instead of me. I want to be notified that there were some changes so I implemented SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener interface. But the listener is never called. I doubt that google's advice is correct because it forgets the listener when Preference activity is displayed. Am I doing something wrong or google tutorial is wrong?

Comment: I posted a complete code. I think that I have the cause. I want to be notified that preferences were changed (and finished) and then modify my activity. But I shall not listen for this in MyActivity which gets suspended once GamePreferenceActivity is started (and listener is removed). I shall update in GamePreferenceActivity some shared preference that there was a change and then compare this value in MyActivity.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way how I register and unregister listener:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
// Register the listener whenever a key changes
getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                    .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        }

@Override
public void onPause() {
super.onPause();   
// Unregister the listener whenever a key changes
getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                        .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
            }
```

Show us your onSharedPreferenceChanged, maybe you made mistake there.

Comment: Where do you register this listener? In preference activity or that one which starts preference activity?

Comment: Im implementing OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener to PreferenceFragment. There is onResume and onPause.

Comment: `getPreferenceScreen()` is depricated. Any alternatives?

Comment: @Srikar Reddy read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756457/android-deprecated-method-warning-regarding-preferenceactivity